# How to store the zip file data

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that i am downloading the zip file from server using nsurlconnection class.Here i need to store the zip data based on response without unzip.And i am doing the Unzip operation after total file downloaded.So please tell me how to save the zip file information based on every response.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just take the responseData from the NSUrlResponse, and do whatever you want.

If you want to store it on the disk, use the writeToFile method.